# Working with property lists

Tags: c#

i want to fill some properties. I get the data from a XML File which i read by using LINQ to XML.

That looks like that:

```
var CharNames = from CharName in doc.Descendants("character").Attributes("name")
                select CharName;
```

my properties looks like that:

```
public List<int> CharClassId { get; set; }
public List<String> CharRace { get; set; }
public List<int> CharRaceId { get; set; }
public List<int> CharGenderId { get; set; }
```

then i want to fill this properties.. actually i use a simple foreach

```
foreach (String s in CharNames)
{
    CharName.Add(s);
}
```

and of course i get a `NullReferenceException`, because the List isn't initialized.

But i can't initialize it by using

```
CharName = new List<String>();
```

what would be a good solution?

maybe i am working in a absolutely wrong way... if it is so please tell me

thx

**EDIT:**

Ok i got the solution.
I simply used the .NET 2.0 property style and made it like:

```
    private List<String> _CharName;
    public List<string> CharName 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_CharName == null)
                _CharName = new List<string>();
            return _CharName;
        }
        set
        {
            _CharName = value;
        }
    }
```

Now my list is getting filled by all names from the xml.

Thanks anyways =)

Comment: CharNames is a variable and how could you use foreach on the Var Charname ? use a list<string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: Or if it applies change it to a field instead of property, then you can use this syntax : `List<String> CharName = new List<String>();`

Comment: And beware that any other constructor should call it because it always must be called upon the object creation.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> CharNames = new List<String>();

CharNames = (from CharName in doc.Descendants("character").Attributes("name")
             select CharName).ToList();
```

Comment: but List<String> CharNames = new List<String>();
isnt a property?

Comment: It'll get rid of your unassignment error as the list with be initialised with the new List<string>. Not 100% sure what you mean with not a property... have you included the System.Collections.Generic namespace?